# New relic agent with Maven integration test

Tags: java, spring, newrelic

I´m using new relic agent for some Test environment of a Spring application, but I´m wondering if would be possible configure the new relic agent to be used in a machine where I execute some Jenkins integration test. The problem is that since the application is up run the integration test using some maven-tomcat-plugin I cannot install properly the new relic agent in the application service since does not exist before start the test.

Anyone has done something like this before.

**SOLUTION:**

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/frameworks/maven-installation-java

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are getting stuck on trying to use the New Relic Java agent's self-installer where in your particular case doing a manual installation (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/java-agent-manual-installation) makes a lot more sense.

Just before Jenkins brings up your application prior to running your tests, insert a snippet that copies the newrelic.jar and newrelic.yml config file with your license key and environment specific configuration and modifies your catalina.sh to add the -javaagent:{path_to_jar_location} flag.